# C++ invalid cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘double’

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

How can I cast a void pointer to a double, retaining the exact binary stored in the void pointer? I thought this could be done with `reinterpret_cast<double>(voidp)`, but g++ doesn't let me. I know you can cast void pointers to integers, so I tried `reinterpret_cast<double>(reinterpret_cast<long>(voidp))`, but apparently that's also invalid. `sizeof(double)` and `sizeof(void*)` are both 8, so it can't be a size thing. Is there anything I can do to accomplish this?

EDIT: The double in this case is not pointed to by the void pointer, but /is/ the void pointer - the pointer itself contains the data I want, it does not point to the data I want.

Comment: Cast it to a `double *`

Comment: `double d = *((double*)voidp)` ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In what situation would you be storing a `double` in a `void*`?

Comment: *"sizeof(double) and sizeof(void*) are both 8"* - did you mean *happen to be both 8*?

Comment: @Eric thread calls often require the signature to be `void* fun( void* )`

Comment: If you target C++11, `std::thread` has a cleaner interface

Comment: @clcto Yes, which is why you pass a *pointer* to a `double`, rather than a `double`.

Comment: I really think giving more context in what you're trying to do would clear up the answers. As it stands, half of us are guessing at what you *really* want to do and going for a cleaner route.

Comment: @Eric True. I think/thought he did use a `double*` but didn't realize it.

Comment: Clarified above: the void pointer is the double, it does not point to the double.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Direct memory reinterpretation, by definition, means working with lvalues. The most straightforward approach would be to do it though a cast to reference type

```
double d = reinterpret_cast<double &>(voidp);
```

You can also do it through a pointer cast, as other answers suggested, although it "overloads" the procedure with a number of completely unnecessary operator applications. Both approaches are equivalent, since by definition `reinterpret_cast` to reference type `reinterpret_cast<T &>(v)` is equivalent to the pointer version `*reinterpret_cast<T *>(&v)`.

However, the above approaches suffer from type-punning issues. Formally, doing this is simply illegal. You are not allowed to read `void *` objects as `double` objects in C++. Direct memory reinterpretation exists in C++ for re-interpreting objects as arrays of `char`s, not for arbitrary type-punning like the above. Even if we ignore the formal issue and stick to purely "practical" considerations, trying to directly reinterpret a `void *` value as `double` value might produce completely unexpected and meaningless results in a compiler that follows strict-aliasing semantics when performing optimizations.

A better idea might be to `memcpy` the `void *` object to the `double` object

```
double d;
assert(sizeof d == sizeof voidp); // <- a static assert would be even better
memcpy(&d, &voidp, sizeof d);
```

Alternatively, in C you are now allowed to use unions for that purpose. I'm not sure the formal permission made into C++ yet, but it will typically work in practice.

Comment: Yay for the `assert()` and `memcpy()`. As to the formal permission in C++: it's still explicitly prohibited (UB) to read an inactive union member.

Comment: I accepted this answer in lieu of the one I accepted first (Avidanborisov's) because you both answered my original question and the suggestion of using a union proved to be more useful.

Comment: The union method, in addition to generally resulting in UB, also may not generate the best code: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959. `memcpy()`, possibly wrapped up in a `bit_cast<>()` template function, should be the preferred method for correctness, safety, and convenience. @Monchoman45

Answer (score 7):

The `memcpy()` method should be your preferred method of type punning:

```
double d = 100;
void *x;
std::memcpy(&x, &d, sizeof x);

std::cout << x << '\n';

double d2;
std::memcpy(&d2, &x, sizeof d2);

std::cout << d2 << '\n';
```

You might think this would be slower than a cast, but in fact compilers are smart enough to recognize what's going on here and generate optimal code: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/959

In addition, this method cannot result in undefined behavior due to aliasing violations as can happen with casts or union methods.

You can write a `bit_cast` operator to make this more convienent and more safe:

http://pastebin.com/n4yDjBde

```
template <class Dest, class Source>
inline Dest bit_cast(Source const &source) {
    static_assert(sizeof(Dest)==sizeof(Source), "size of destination and source objects must be equal");
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Dest>::value, "destination type must be trivially copyable.");
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Source>::value, "source type must be trivially copyable");

    Dest dest;
    std::memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof(dest));
    return dest;
}
```

Example usage:

```
void *p = ...;
double d = bit_cast<double>(p);
```

If you do type punning you ought to be aware of trap values for the involved types and your compiler's behavior with traps and unspecified values.

Comment: Why would he do that?

Comment: @LihO I have no idea, but he clearly asked to take the bit pattern of a `void*` and get a `double` with the same bit pattern.

Comment: @LihO Actually I can think of one use: there are many callback APIs that allow you to pass a `void*` to the callback. If the callback only takes a double and a user wants to avoid putting the doubles on the heap, and `void*` happens to be large enough, then passing the double directly as the `void*` value may have the desired performance characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

This is not recommended at all, but if you have to, use:

```
*reinterpret_cast<double*>(&voidp)
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to take the address of the void*, although maybe that's what he's trying to do. Who knows :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for - I think I should have clarified that the void pointer /is/ the double, it doesn't actually point to anything.

Comment: @Monchoman45: Why would you pass a `double` in form of `void*`? What kind of sorcery forced you to go that low?

Comment: @Monchoman45 It was clear from the question, however most people assumed that your code was doing something sane and you were wrong about your code, rather than believing you.

Comment: Be prepared though, that this might not work as expected in a compiler that performs strict-aliasing optimizations.

Comment: @LihO & EricFinn: throwaway code. It doesn't have to be good, it just has to work.

Comment: I think they don't understand your reason for using it at all. If you need a `double`, why don't you use one?

Comment: This can fail if `double` has stricter alignment requirements than `void*`. I think `memcpy()` is the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
void* some_void_data = NULL;
double* as_double = static_cast<double*>(some_void_data);
double as_double_copy = *as_double;
double as_double_copy_one_line = *static_cast<double*>(some_void_data);
```

Obviously you'd want to apply the cast to a non-null pointer in real usage. `static_cast` can only be used to convert from one pointer type to another pointer type. If you want a copy of the pointer you're expected to perform the copy yourself by dereferencing the pointer returned by the cast.

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) is a good resource on casting.